# Single command with git add to ignore untracked files

Tags: git

I am using `git add .`  to add all files , ie modified, new files and without deleted one. But while using this one, it is accepting all `untracked` files too.  Is there a single command that can combine with `git add .`to ignore untracked files. ?

git version: 2.28.0 on windows 10 :

```
git status
git add .  *single command to combine with git add . to ignore untracked files*
git commit -m"commit message"
git push
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `git add -u`. It will stage all modified files but not untracked files.

> -u
>
> --update
>
> Update the index just where it already has an entry matching <pathspec>. This removes as well as modifies index entries to match the working tree, but adds no new files.
>
> If no <pathspec> is given when -u option is used, all tracked files in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).

[Source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--u)

Comment: Thank you, so the usage is `git add -u` with out dot  ? will it add all files modified, new and not deleted one

Comment: It will add modified and deleted files, not new/untracked files. Optionally, you can specify a pathspec (i.e. `git add -u foo/bar`) to only stage for example one folder.

Comment: Or, if by "new" you mean a file that has previously been staged but not yet committed, then yes, it will stage those too.

Comment: Yes `new` I means , the file which has not been commited yet and has been staged to commit..